# Java GridLayout is laying out all my JPanels in the top left corner

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, grid-layout

SOLVED:

Just found out what the problem was, after trying to make an SSCCE.

It had to do with my cell class, I didn't realise I was overriding getX() and getY() from the JComponent class.

After renaming these accessors it all works as expected

========================================

I have a JPanel with a GridLayout set at 3 rows x 3 cols.

I'm trying to add JPanels to each cell in the gridlayout to fill up all 9 cells.
Each one of these JPanels has an overriden paintChildren method which will paint some kind of rectangle starting at the top left of the JPanel - the end result will be each cell has a rectangle in it starting at the top left of the cell.

After adding all the JPanels to the gridlayout, they all appear in the top left corner overlapping each other (I have confirmed they are overlapping), instead of being laid out in a 3x3 grid.

How can I get them arranged in the 3x3 grid?

(Simplified) Code:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {

public Panel(int x, int y) {
    layout = new GridLayout(x, y, 2, 2);
    setLayout(layout);

    populateGrid();
}

public void populateGrid() {

    removeAll();

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        add(new Cell(50,50));
}
}

public class Cell extends JPanel {

public Cell(int x, int y) {
    // x/y values used to define rectangle
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(0,0,0)));
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

}

public void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, x, y);
}
}
```

Comment: *"(Simplified) Code:"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) rather than uncompilable code snippets.

Comment: Have a look at [these notes](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci230s2c/lectures/angela/10AwtSwing.pdf). They come with examples and also cover the Panel layout etc.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you import the right `Panel`. (And not the `java.awt.Panel` class.) Or, better, rename your class to `GridPanel` or something similar to avoid confusion / clashes.
- You probably don't want to override `paintChildren`. Overriding `paintComponent` sounds like a better option in this case.
- You may want to set minimum / preferred / maximum size for the `Cell` class.

Hard to make more observations without the actual code that instantiates and uses your `Panel` class.

Comment: Yeah - I've renamed them for posting up on here, the actual name is more meaningful.

I'm instantiating the Panel by using: new Panel(3, 3);, and it gets placed in the center of a borderlayout